# How to fix ionic tab icon display different on Android an iOS devices?

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm changing my ionic tab button style to make the center button bigger than the others.In my Android devices, it looks normal, but when I deploy to my iOS devices, the center button displays incorrectly. 
Where do I need to change to fix the style issue?

```
.ion-ios-homeImg:before{
  content: '';
  width: 60px;
  height:60px;
  display: block;
  background: no-repeat center url("../assets/imgs/scantab.png");
  background-size: contain;
}

.ion-ios-homeImg-outline:before{
  content: '';
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  display: block;
  background: no-repeat center url("../assets/imgs/scantab.png");
  background-size: contain;  
}
.ion-md-homeImg:before{
  content: '';
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  display: block;
  background: no-repeat center url("../assets/imgs/scantab.png");
  background-size: contain; 
}

.tab-button-icon{
  overflow: visible;
}

.tab-button.has-icon.icon-only.disable-hover {
  position: relative;
  .tab-button-icon{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 16px;
    left: calc(50% - 30px);
    z-index: 9999999;
}
```

1.Android 
    https://github.com/yl847866341/Heart/blob/master/QQ20190125-0.png
2.iOS
    https://github.com/yl847866341/Heart/blob/master/Screenshot_2019-01-25-11-05-39-185_com.legend.sta.png

Answer (score 0):

I debug my app on simulator and change the bottom to 30px.The problem was solved.